# How to retrieve user selections from a previous form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have several forms that take people through steps and below are the first two and the simplest ones and makes it easy to explain what i am having problem with.

The following two views are login required and contain one form on each. First view is the new_operator where the user fills out a single text input field. Second view is the new_asset where the user fills one text input field as the asset name and selects an operator from the a select/dropdown field. The question is how can i get the form to remember the operator name the user created in the previous form and make it as the default option? To be clear, i still want the user to select any other operator if they choose to do so but i want the option they just created to be the default. Thanks a lot in advance for the help.

**First, here are the models:**

```
class OperatorCompany(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='operator_added_by', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Operator Company"
    verbose_name_plural = "Operator Companies"

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class AssetName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    operator = models.ForeignKey(OperatorCompany, related_name='asset', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='asset_added_by', null=True, 
                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Asset"
    verbose_name_plural = "Assets"

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
def new_operator(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NewOperatorForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        newoperator = form.save(commit=False)
        newoperator.created_by = request.user
        newoperator.created_at = timezone.now()
        newoperator.save()
        return redirect('wellsurfer:new_asset')
else:
    form = NewOperatorForm()
return render(request, 'wellsurfer/create_new_operator.html', {'create_operator': form})

def new_asset(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NewAssetForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        newasset = form.save(commit=False)
        newasset.created_by = request.user
        newasset.created_at = timezone.now()
        newasset.save()
        return redirect('wellsurfer:new_pad')
else:
    form = NewAssetForm()
return render(request, 'wellsurfer/create_new_asset.html', {'create_asset': form})
```

**and following are the forms.py without the init, clean functions and the widgets**

```
class NewOperatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OperatorCompany
        fields = ('name',)


class NewAssetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AssetName
        fields = ('name', 'operator')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share data between multiple pages, you can use [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) variables. These are stored on the server and associated to clients according to the session cookie they communicate to the server at every request.

Typically, in the first view, you would add after `save()`:

```
request.session['latest_created_operator_id'] = newoperator.id
```

to save in the session the operator id.

And in the second view, after the `else`,

```
operator_id = request.session.get('latest_created_operator_id', None)
operator = Operator.objects.filter(id=operator_id).first() # returns None if not found
form = NewAssetForm(initial={'operator': operator})
```

retrieves the operator and populates the form.

(That's untested code; you may need to edit a bit.)

Comment: this just works beautifully. Thank you! I querying the latest record in the database in forms.py and assigning it as the initial value. Your was is much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, maybe something like this would work.

What you can do is add another URL in `urls.py` for new_asset which accepts a OperatorCompany id. I don't have your url config but it could be something like:

**urls.py**

```
path('wellsurfer/new_asset/<int:operator_id>', new_asset, name='wellsurfer:new_asset_operator')
```

**view.py**

```
def new_operator(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NewOperatorForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        newoperator = form.save(commit=False)
        newoperator.created_by = request.user
        newoperator.created_at = timezone.now()
        newoperator.save()
        return redirect('wellsurfer:new_asset', operator_id=newoperator.id)
else:
    form = NewOperatorForm()
return render(request, 'wellsurfer/create_new_operator.html', {'create_operator': form})

def new_asset(request, operator_id=None):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NewAssetForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        newasset = form.save(commit=False)
        newasset.created_by = request.user
        newasset.created_at = timezone.now()
        newasset.save()
        return redirect('wellsurfer:new_pad')
else:
    form = NewAssetForm()
    if operator_id is not None:
         operator_company = OperatorCompany.objects.get(pk=operator_id)
         form.fields['operator'].initial = operator_company 
return render(request, 'wellsurfer/create_new_asset.html', {'create_asset': form})
```